# My android app shows temporary name (Package name) in the play store and (Unreviewed)

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

I created my one day ago, and the app is in the review process.
[image]
And when I add internal or close tester, they see the temporary name of the app, without any app logo, description or anything,
[image]
it just my package name as a app name, I complete the store listing, the apps is in review now, when the temporary name will remove and how long It take to in review process?

Answer (score 0):

1. **Review Process for Internal/Closed Testing:**

> Your app in the internal or closed testing phase is not under review
> in the same way as when it is submitted to production. Internal
> testing allows you and other testers to access the app without the
> need for a full review.

2. **App Information and Name Update:**

> The temporary name, lacking logo, description, etc., will persist
> until you submit all the necessary information for release. This
> involves completing the store listing, including the correct app name,
> logo, and description.

3. **Timing for Name Update:**

> After completing the store listing and submitting the app for review
> in the internal or closed testing phase, the process to update the
> temporary name may not be immediate. There is a waiting period
> involved.

According to Play Console Help [Link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859751?hl=en#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20your%20app%20will,learn%20more%20about%20Standard%20publishing.)
"By default, your app will use standard publishing. Certain apps may be subject to extended reviews, which may result in review times of **up to 7 days or longer** in exceptional cases."

4. **Release and Correct App Name:**

> Once your app passes the review process, either for internal testing
> or production release, the temporary name will be updated to the
> correct one you intended during the submission.

5. **Personal Observation:**

> In some cases, even if an app is designated to stay in internal
> testing and not move to production, completing all the necessary tasks
> for release may still trigger the update of the app's name. It may not
> happen immediately, but over time, the correct name will replace the
> temporary one.

In summary, ensure that you have provided all the required information for release, and after a waiting period, your app's temporary name should be updated to the correct one once it passes the review process, even in the internal or closed testing phase.

Comment: I want my testers can see my actual app name, logos and all that, should I wait until the review process to complete?